# iOS 11 flashes springboard with cover unlock

Tags: ipad, ios11

When our iPads are in a cover and our app is running, then the cover is closed, the device sleeps as expected. (It is a third-party cover, not an Apple Smart Cover.)

When the cover is opened, the device awakens as expected, but for a split second it flashes the iPad home screen before displaying our app. (There is no lock code set.)

It is almost unnoticeable, but it varies, not aided I am sure by the fact that our app is very heavy.

iOS 10 did not do this.

Perhaps this sounds like a minor issue, but we are using the iPads as public-facing kiosks and the flashing to springboard looks bad and also shatters the illusion of a dedicated device.

I have toggled every relevant setting to no avail.  It happens to every app so it is not specific to ours.

Our devices are managed via MDM, if it matters, but this issue occurs both while in Single App Mode and when not, and even with MDM removed.

It also happens on iOS 12.

Anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks